# multiple hadoop-env.sh with .deb hadoop package

Tags: configuration, deb, hadoop

[this](http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/GettingStartedWithHadoop) QuickStart guide mentions configuring JAVA_HOME in hadoop-env.sh. This is supposed to be located in the hadoop installation directory. However, I installed 
this from a 1.0.4 .deb package on Ubuntu 12.04. This creates multiple 
hadoop-env.sh and the startup scripts at /usr/sbin. I'm not sure which hadoop-env.sh i should use for my configuration. A related question is what directory should be specified as HADOOP_HOME.

from the wiki:

> HADOOP_HOME is the parent directory of the bin directory that holds the Hadoop scripts

i'm sure they don't mean the parent of /usr/sbin though.

```
$> locate hadoop-env.sh
```

yields:

```
/etc/default/hadoop-env.sh
/etc/hadoop/hadoop-env.sh
/etc/profile.d/hadoop-env.sh
/usr/sbin/update-hadoop-env.sh
/usr/share/hadoop/templates/conf/hadoop-env.sh
```

I am also using [this](http://www.michael-noll.com/tutorials/running-hadoop-on-ubuntu-linux-single-node-cluster/) for reference since I'm setting up a single-node cluster.  I think I downloaded the deb package from Cloudera but I can't recall at the moment and I'm considering restarting the installation

Answer (score 1):

I think that `/etc/hadoop/hadoop-env.sh` is a right file to edit.

I also set up Hadoop according to the tutorial you mentioned but I downloaded a Hadoop distribution from [Apache website](http://hadoop.apache.org/).